# How to turn off a task after a message prompt confirmation

Tags: javascript, angular, aspnetboilerplate

I have a basic application.

When the button is triggered, I set my loading value to true.

```
vm.loading = true;
```

which then turns on my spinner in the background.

We are currently using asp .net boilerplate message prompts, I would like to have the spinner to occur when the message has is confirmed.

Current simplified code, spinner doesn't appear at all.

```
vm.uploadImage = function() {
    abp.message.confirm(('Do you want to continue'), 
    function (isConfirmed){
        if (isConfirmed){
            vm.loading = true; 
            //  do work here //
            vm.loading = false;
        }            
    });
}
```

To get the spinner working, I had to move vm.loading outside of the message prompt. But doing so I'm unable to disable the loading prompt. May I ask how do I disable to correctly fix the spinner.

```
vm.uploadImage = function() {
    vm.loading = true; 
    abp.message.confirm(('Do you want to continue'), 
    function (isConfirmed){
        if (isConfirmed){                
            //  do work here //
        }            
    }).then(function () {
        vm.loading = false;
    });
}
```

I've also tried putting the loading before and after the message, but it doesn't wait for the message prompt to complete.

Comment: Is this in angular version `1.xx` or `2+`?

Comment: @charlietfl Angular 2+